# how to solve error possibly 'null' and type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'. typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hey sorry for the bad english I hope you guys understand what I mean. I have this code below but I get error for **file** Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob' and for **e.target.files** is possibly 'null' here's the screenshot of error.Do you guys know how to solve this error? please tell me how to solve this error and please do tell me in detail what need to change or add because I am really new to typescript

[image: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'.]

[image: e.target.files' is possibly 'null']

```
function ImageLoader({ image, callback, size }) {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<string>("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState<any>(null);
  const [crop, toogleCrop] = useReducer((currCrop) => !currCrop, false);
  const [imageState, setImage] = useState(image);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setResult(reader.result);
      toogleCrop();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }, [file]);

  return (
    <>
      <label
        className="logo"
        style={{
          width: size,
          height: size,
          backgroundSize: size,
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageState})`
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          style={{
            display: "none"
          }}
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setFile(e.target.files[0]);
          }}
        />
      </label>
      {crop ? (
        <ImageCroper
          image={result}
          setCropedImage={(newImage) => {
            setImage(newImage);
            toogleCrop();
            callback(newImage);
          }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you passing a string ("file") to `readAsDataURl` which it expects a `Blob` arg and you also have a runtime error, it arrives when the `e.target.files` are null. To solve this you have to change types of file, result, and imageState.

**Example**

```
function ImageLoader({ image, callback, size }) {

  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [result, setResult] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [crop, toogleCrop] = useReducer((currCrop) => !currCrop, false);
  const [imageState, setImage] = useState<string | null>(image);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setResult(reader.result as string);
      toogleCrop();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }, [file]);

  return (
    <>
      <label
        className="logo"
        style={{
          width: size,
          height: size,
          backgroundSize: size,
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageState})`,
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          style={{
            display: "none",
          }}
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const selectedFile = e.target.files?.[0];
            if (selectedFile) {
              setFile(selectedFile);
            }
          }}
        />
      </label>
      {crop ? (
        <ImageCroper
          image={result || ""}
          setCropedImage={(newImage) => {
            setImage(newImage);
            toogleCrop();
            callback(newImage);
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```